# Does HTML video load block other HTML requests?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have a webpage which has a background video (HTML5 < video > ) which loads automatically (upon pageload). I've noticed that when I click on links on that page, it takes a really long time for the browser to respond and to then take me to the linked page.

Does the browser wait for the video to complete loading before it then starts processing the new request (link clicked)?

If so, how can I change this behaviour (so that the video stops loading upon a link being clicked, or other on-page behaviour)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers will have differ implementations but the major ones generally support multiple parallel network requests by default, so a page can download multiple resource in parallel.

You can see this in practice by enabling and opening the tools for your browser and viewing the network or timeline tab/view, depending on the particular browser.

For example, look at the waterfall tab in the image below, from Chrome Developer Tools, and you can see parallel downloads:

[image]

Ultimately, all the requests have to share the same network connection (usually) so large downloads may slow your overall page performance.